# Android eclipse emulator flashes white screen

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with android emulator, after a while of working with the emulator, installing and testing codes, the emulator screen start to flash white screens until its almost impossible to show the app behind.

The avd is configured as "USE GPU" (without this I have black screen) and S4 settings (1080x1920, 4.99 screen, 1512MB RAM - tried also less then this (I have 8GB RAM installed), normal screen, xxhdpi).

If someone knows how to fix it please advise asap.

Thanks in advance,
Woody.

Answer (score 1):

very simple do not use GPU host unchecked it it work for me
try to use 
android 4.0.3
Intel X86
RAM 512

Answer (score 0):

its very strange problem u have, u can always try to create new avd's..try skin with 1280*800
the device name would be 10.1 WXGA TABLET, or any other.. or any other.. n try not using GPU HOST..